# Why is closest() and text() with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, closest

I have a special case, where I would like to get the text of a DIV element with a specific class name, which is the closest to the selected text. There could be several DIVs with the same class name, so I try to get the closest one. 
I get the selected text and the HTMLDIVELEMENT, where the selected text is, from getSelectionTextAndContainerElement().
Now I try to find the closest DIV element with the class blogUser.
Hier my HTML code:

```
    <div class = "tHead">
    <div class = "tRow">
        <div class = "tCell">
<h1>{sBlogs.0.blogName}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <f:for each="{sBlogs}" as="blog">
        <div class = "tSub">
            <div class = "tRow">
                <div class = "tCell blogUser">
    User: {blog.blogUser}
                </div>
                <div class = "tCell blogDate">
    Date: {blog.blogDate -> f:format.date()}
                </div>
                <div class = "tCell blogCat">
    Category: {blog.blogCat}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "content">
    {blog.blogContent}
        </div>
        <div class="links">
        <f:image class="reply" src="EXT:simpleblog/Resources/Public/Icons/search.svg" />
        </div>

    </f:for>
<div class="replyBlog">
    <f:form.textarea class="editBlog" property="editBlog" rows="10" cols="80"/>
</div>
<f:form.button type="button" class = "sButton editSave" title = "editSave" id = "editSave" name = "editSave">Speichern</f:form.button>
</f:form>
```

and this is my js code

```
    $(".reply").on("click",function(){
    var textEl = getSelectionTextAndContainerElement();
    var className= "div."+textEl['containerElement']['className'];
    var divC=$(className).closest("div.tRow");
    alert(divC);
    var divC2=divC.find('div.blogUser');
    var bUser=divC2.text();
    alert(bUser);
    var text1=bUser+"\n"+textEl['text'];
    alert(text1);
    $(".editBlog").val(text1);
```

First I tried:

```
        var divC=$(className).closest("div.blogUser").text();
```

but the text() function returned always an empty string.
The interesting thing is, if I select the div directly, it returns a string

```
$("div.blogUser").text();
```

The vars divC and divC2 gets  jquery OBJECTs, but if I use the objects with text(), no value is returned.

I have no idea what the problem is! Hope sombody can help me.

Comment: That tells me your `className` object is invalid and\or the `closest()` method is not the right choice for traversing. Keep in mind, you cannot mix native JS with JQuery. JQuery ***requires*** that it be a JQuery object (i.e. `$(object)`).

Comment: I don't see that I mixed up JS with JQUERY. From the JS object I got the class name and from there up it is pure JQUERY. Maybe closest is not the right way, but what is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem without closest.
First I wraped an addition

I also converted the HTMLDIVOBJECT to a jQuery object, to make sure I am in the right block.
Here my final code:

```
    <div class = "tHead">
    <div class = "tRow">
        <div class = "tCell">
<h1>{sBlogs.0.blogName}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <f:for each="{sBlogs}" as="blog">
    <div class="block">
        <div class = "tSub">
            <div class = "tRow">
                <div class = "tCell blogUser">
    User: {blog.blogUser}
                </div>
                <div class = "tCell blogDate">
    Date: {blog.blogDate -> f:format.date()}
                </div>
                <div class = "tCell blogCat">
    Category: {blog.blogCat}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "content">
    {blog.blogContent}
        </div>
        <div class="links">
        <f:image class="reply" src="EXT:simpleblog/Resources/Public/Icons/search.svg" />
        </div>
    </div>

    </f:for>
    <div class="replyBlog">
        <f:form.textarea class="editBlog" property="editBlog" rows="10" cols="80"/>
    </div>
<f:form.button type="button" class = "sButton editSave" title = "editSave" id = "editSave" name = "editSave">Speichern</f:form.button>
</f:form>
```

jquery:

```
    $(".reply").on("click",function(){
    var textEl = getSelectionTextAndContainerElement();
    var bUser = jQuery(textEl['containerElement']).parent().find('div.blogUser').text();
    alert('Container: \n'+bUser);
    var text1 = bUser+"\n"+textEl['text'];
    alert(text1);
    $(".editBlog").val(text1);
});
```